# If noindex pages don't have H1, meta tags, or other desirable elements for SEO, will it hurt the SEO of indexed pages?

Tags: seo, googlebot, noindex, technical-seo

I have some pages with noindex. These pages have some SEO errors. SEO errors include:

- not using H1
- Not using meta tags
- Not adding `alt=""` tags to images

But there no such SEO problems on my other indexed pages. In addition, noindex pages receive traffic through social media, so Google knows these pages. Will it do any harm to my other pages even though noindex pages are not read by google?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope! Google ranks **pages** not **websites**. Since they are pages that you do not want to have indexed, you do not need to optimize them.

Do be mindful of your users though! You *should* add `alt` text to your images for accessibility. This tag is designed for accommodating users with visual impairments or other disabilities.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply.

Comment: @ardacar Thank you for the great questions!